# Unknown type name 'XMLParser'; did you mean 'NSXMLParser'?

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, parsing

Why I get this error **"Unknown type name 'XMLParser'; did you mean 'NSXMLParser'?"** ? I have imported XMLParser.h, so I can't understand what the problem is.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "televisionList.h"
#import "ListingCell.h"

@interface TelevisionDetail : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    XMLParser *xmlParser;
}
@end
```

Comment: Where does *XMLParser.h* come from ?

Comment: I added XMLParser.h and XMLParser.m from another project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Xcode bug, but also it's a good practice to avoid unnecessary import in .h file.

So try to add this before `@interface..`:

```
@class XMLParser;
```

And add `#import "XMLParser.h"` in your .m file.

Comment: Agreed ! I think it's better to always use *@class* in your .h and *#import* in your .m